# Augmented reality on the water

Tags: augmented-reality, arkit, arcore

I am building mobile app which is presenting content on the water.

I would like to present content using AR - 3D content and location markers.

Surface detection is impossible in that case - tell me I am wrong.

On the other hand on the water gravity ensures flatness on the surface.

Is there a way to provide surface manually or maybe I should change the approach to the problem?

I have tested ARKit directly on the water. Sometimes origin was pinned to the deck of the boat and it was jumping to many places.

The only partial solution I see right now is HDAugmentedReality library or Wikitude SDK. Both of them can display markers using geolocation without surface detection but that's only markers.

Answer (score 3):

#### Water and glass refraction in AR

`Refractive`/`reflective` objects like **water**, **glass**, **mirror**, **chrome**, etc. are bad targets for camera tracking and/or plane detection. Textures on these objects are constantly "changing" (depending on PoV or, in case of water, due to wind's direction that affects a shape and refraction angle of waves). **So you cannot rely on these surfaces**.

For stable *World Tracking* and high-quality *Plane Detection* you need static well-lit objects like walls, tables or floor, not objects with dynamic refraction/reflection. Look at **[this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53256147/android-unable-to-detect-vertical-plane/53260589#53260589)** for details.

Although, under certain conditions you sometimes can use glass objects for object/image recognition in AR app. Look at **[this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52745207/object-detection-arkit-vs-coreml/52751279#52751279)** to find out how to use them in your environment.

Answer (score 3):

As @ARGeo said, reflective materials are untrackable.

An alternative could be using lat/lon from GPS and make a projection at altidute 0 (sea level).

The problem in this case is that the altitude is the altitude **above the WGS84 reference ellipsoid**. 
It is **not the altitude above ground level or sea level**.

Here is more detail on that: http://www.gpspassion.com/forumsen/topic.asp?TOPIC_ID=10915.

This error can be corrected; here is a description how to do that by hand: http://www.unavco.org/edu_outreach/tutorial/geoidcorr.html.

The web article links to a calculator to get the Geoid height for correction; I do not know if there is also a web service available for this computation.

Other than that you have to stabilize GPS signal, as the error margin could be relevant at every computation.